# Cybersource secure acceptance hosted checkout fails and require billing information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cybersource

I am using asp.net for integrating cybersource payment gateway. I successfully gone to payment page but after filling card details and Pay, order automatically declined. When i search in Cybersource dashboard i get below error.

**Client App**
Secure Acceptance Web/Mobile
**Reason Code**
101
**Reply Message**
The request data did not pass the required fields check for this application: [bill_address1, bill_city, bill_country, customer_email, customer_lastname]
**Reply**
Incomplete Request Data
**Reply Code**
0
**Applications**
Credit Card Authorization

for example, i am sending below address in hidden fields

```
<input type="hidden" name="access_key" value="myaccess_key">
    <input type="hidden" name="profile_id" value="myprofile_id">
    <input type="hidden" name="transaction_uuid" value="mytransaction_uuid">
    <input type="hidden" name="signed_field_names" value="access_key,profile_id,bill_address1,bill_city,bill_country,customer_email,customer_lastname,transaction_uuid,signed_field_names,unsigned_field_names,signed_date_time,locale,transaction_type,reference_number,amount,currency">
    <input type="hidden" name="unsigned_field_names" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="signed_date_time" value="mytime">
    <input type="hidden" name="locale" value="en">
    <input type="hidden" name="bill_address1" value="test"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="bill_city" value="London"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="bill_country" value="GB"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="customer_email" value="test@test.test"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="customer_lastname" value="TEST"/>
```

and so on..........

Answer (score 1):

The name that you have given in hidden input control for billing address is not the right one. Try with the below names it was working for me.

```
<input type="hidden" name="bill_to_address_line1" value="test"/>
<input type="hidden" name="bill_to_address_city" value="London"/>
<input type="hidden" name="bill_to_address_country" value="GB"/>
<input type="hidden" name="bill_to_email" value="test@test.test"/>
<input type="hidden" name="bill_to_surname" value="TEST"/>
```